# NodeJs/Firestore/React- Storing Firestore query results into the state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class called user in which it has all the methods and instnace variables a user class would need. In it, i have a method which is responsible for returning query results to an index.js file. In this index.js file, i was hoping to set the state with the value from the query. But this does not work.

```
function collectres () {
  var store ='';
  var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
  docRef.get()
    .then(function (doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        store = doc.data();// when referenced outside, it doesnt hold anything.
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  return store; // returns nothing and seems to not notice the assignment.
}
```

The function above was within my user class. When referenced from the index, it would look like this.

```
Random() {
    let a = '';
    a = user.collectres();
    this.setState({name:a});
    console.log(this.state.name);
}
```

however this would set the state with the previous value. When looking at the console log, i have noticed, the order of logging starts first with the index.js console.log(this.state.name),however shouldnt my collect res's log's show first.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. The rest of your code continues to execute while the data is being loaded, and then your `then` callback is called once the data is there.

It's easiest to see this with a few well-placed log statements:

```
console.log("Starting to load data");
docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
  console.log("Got data");
});
console.log("Started to load data");
```

When you run this it prints:

> Starting to load data
>
> Started to load data
>
> Got data

This probably isn't the output you expected, but it completely explains the behavior you're seeing. Right now your `return store` runs *before* the `store = doc.data()`, which explains why you're not getting the result you want.

---

This means that any code that needs the data, needs to be inside the `then()` callback. So if you move the call to `setState()` to right after `store = doc.data()`, it will work:

```
docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    store = doc.data();
    this.setState({name: store});
  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
})
```

---

Alternatively, you can return the value from within the `then()` upwards. In that case you'll need a `then()` in your calling code too:

```
function collectres () {
  var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
  return docRef.get()
    .then(function (doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        return doc.data();
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

And then call it with:

```
Random() {
    let a = '';
    user.collectres().then(function(a) {
      this.setState({name:a});
    });
}
```

---

Asynchronous APIs are extremely common in modern programming, so I highly recommend reading up on them. For more information, see:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [Why are the Firebase API asynchronous?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)
- [Learn JavaScript Promises with Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA)
- [React + Firestore : Return a variable from a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530492/react-firestore-return-a-variable-from-a-query)
- [Javascript firebase firestore function not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020388/javascript-firebase-firestore-function-not-executing)